# How can I get anotation latitude and longitude in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

is this possible to get anotation point latitude and longitude in

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {


}
```

In this function

Comment: why dont you look in the documenattion at MKAnnotation?

Comment: I have checked man.. but didn't get it.. still thanks for reply

Comment: the pin is marked with the help of latitude and longitude only.please get the lat and long form the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
annotation.coordinate.latitude
annotation.coordinate.longitude
```

But @AlexWien is right ... a quick overview to documentation let you discover this easily ...

Answer (score -1):

In [MkAnnotaion](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), The first property is the coordinate.